# Regex - Cost of an Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

What is the regular expression to check a cost has been provided correctly:

- Number must be greater than or equal to 0.01
- Number must be less than or equal to 99.99

Possible matches are:

9 | 23.3 | 25.69

Not allowed:

1. | 2.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing you do NOT do with a regular expression.

Comment: Should `.01` and `1.` be valid?

Comment: I don't think it's feasible to do this with Regular Expressions.  Regular Expressions are meant to be a text processing language, what you are asking for is the processing of values.  I'd be interested to hear if someone thinks otherwise though.

Comment: @CodingG You can do this. It is a finite set of valid values, so it is indeed possible.

Comment: @lasseespeholt Anything is doable, it doesn't mean you _should_ do it.  He didn't mention any languages or environments, but I have to believe there is a better way in whatever he's using.

Comment: @lasseespeholt, the key word is *feasible*. **CodingG** did not say impossible. This is simply not something you *should* do with a regex.

Comment: @lasseespeholt - yes .01 should be valid

Comment: @CodingG I did not say he should do it. I just said it is possible. I guess I read "feasible" as ~"possible".

Comment: @freshest, what other technologies are you using so you can receive a *quality* answer.

Comment: @lasseespeholt - 1. not valid

Comment: @CodingG "Anything is doable" is simply false. Most things are not doable with reg. exp. (~regular languages + some specials).

Comment: This is for form validation in Ruby on Rails.  I am using the helper validates_format_of.  I am trying to validate that the user has submitted a valid cost ie it has to be more than 0.01 and less than 99.99.

Comment: @freshest: You say that .01 is valid, yet in your question you explicitly state that 0.01 is not valid (Number must be *greater than* 0.01).

Comment: @Zano - thanks, have just edited question.

Comment: @lasseespeholt - I meant that in a generalized sense, I wasn't speaking directly to Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the correct way would be to take the provided string, convert it to a number (catching errors if it's not a parseable number) and then compare that with the valid values.

If it *has* to be a regex, it's of course possible but ugly:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|0?.0[1-9]|0?.[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # start of string
(?:                 # either match
 [1-9][0-9]?        # a number between 1 and 99
 (?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?  # optionally followed by a decimal point and up to two digits
|                   # or
 0?.0[1-9]          # a number between 0.01 and 0.09 (optionally without leading 0)
|                   # or
 0?.[1-9][0-9]?     # a number between 0.1 and 0.99
)                   # end of alternation
$                   # end of string
```

Of course, in most regex dialects, you can use `\d` in place of `[0-9]` without a change in meaning, but I think in this case sticking to the longer version helps readability.

In Ruby, assuming your input string never contains a newline:

```
if subject =~ /^(?:[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|0?.0[1-9]|0?.[1-9][0-9]?)$/
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

Since you care about the number of significant digits, another solution would be to first check if the input looks like a number, and if it passes that test, convert it to a float and check if it's in range.

```
^(\d{1,2}|\d{0,2}\.\d{1,2})$
```

would match any number (integer or decimal up to two digits after the decimal point) between 0 and 99.99. Then you just need to check whether the number is >= 0.01. The advantage of this approach is that you can easily extend the range of digits allowed before/after the decimal point if the requirements for valid numbers change, and then adjust the value check accordingly.

Comment: The regex works great, thank you so much. I am doing this in RoR, can you show me how you would do it?

Comment: Is a regular interval check the best way to do this, as @Zano has suggested?

Comment: It sure seems like the more natural thing to do, especially if your requirements change - imagine that tomorrow you'll need to validate numbers between 0.07 and 218.39.

Comment: I can't seem to iterate with a float, `(0.01..99.99) === 2.2222` returns true and I want it to return false, any ideas?

Comment: 2.2222 is between 0.01 and 99.99, so of course it returns True. I will amend my answer.

Comment: So do you think the regex way is better than the regular interval check?

Comment: A combination of both sounds like a good idea. Depends on what you really need. If you never will need to validate a different range of values, the regex way is fine. If that is not certain, then you lose flexibility if you're trying to do everything at once with a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you need to do this using regular expression why dont you just split the string on '|' into an array and check each element in array is greater than 0.01 and less than 99.99

Answer (score 2):

A solution using a regexp would be hard to maintain since it is a very strange and unintuitive way to solve the problem. It would be hard for anyone reading your code  (including yourself in a couple of weeks) to understand what the purpose of the check is.

That said, assuming values 0.00 - 99.99 are valid, the regexp could be

```
^\d{0,2}(\.\d\d?)?$
```

Assuming 0.01 - 99.99, it's a bit more complicated:

```
^0{0,2}(\.(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?))?|\d{0,2}(\.\d\d)?$
```

And don't get me started on 0.02 - 99.98... :-)

So basically, don't do this. Convert the string to a numerical value and then do a regular interval check.

Comment: How do I do a regular interval check?

Comment: something like `if (0.01..99.99) === inputValue` or `if (0.01..99.99).include?(inputValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

it checks whether there are 1 or 2 digits and optionally if there is a dot it checks if there are 1 or 2 digits after the dot.

as answer to the comments of your question: nothing speaks against checking for the format before sending the request to a server or something else. range checks could be done somewhere else.

Comment: But as he states in the question, it's not a format check, it's a range check.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best but works

```
(0\.01|0\.02|0\.03| ... |99\.98|99\.99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in Rails, you might be better served using `validates_numericality_of` in your model:

```
validates_numericality_of :cost, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01, 
                                 :less_than_or_equal_to => 0.99
```

To prevent fractional pennies, use this in conjunction with `validates_format_of`:

```
validates_format_of :cost, :with => /\A\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\Z/
```

This leverages the strength of each validation.

Comment: This would allow 1.2333 for example.